# Dataproc Initialization Script not running on master node

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm setting up a new dataproc server and using initilization-action to run a custom script. The script runs fine on 2 datanodes but not executing on master node.

Tried looking for logs under /var/log/dataprog-initilization-*.log but unable to find the file in the master node.

Has anyone else faced this issue before?
Thanks in advance!!

**gcloud command:**

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create test-cluster \
--region=us-central1 --zone=us-central1-a \
--master-machine-type=n1-standard-4 --master-boot-disk-size=200 \
--initialization-actions=gs://dp_init_data/init2.sh --initialization-action-timeout="2m" \
--num-workers=2 --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-8 --worker-boot-disk-size=200
```

**DataNode error log:**

```
2019-07-11 03:29:22,123 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool BP-268987178-10.32.1.248-1562675355441 (Datanode Uuid 71664f82-1d23-4184-b19b-28f86b01a251) service to exp-gcp-kerberos-m.c.exp-cdh-prod.internal/10.32.1.248:8051 Datanode denied communication with namenode because the host is not in the include-list: DatanodeRegistration(10.32.1.60:9866, datanodeUuid=71664f82-1d23-4184-b19b-28f86b01a251, infoPort=0, infoSecurePort=9865, ipcPort=9867, storageInfo=lv=-57;cid=CID-aee57974-1706-4b8c-9654-97da47ad0464;nsid=128710770;c=1562675355441)
```

Comment: This is unusual. Can you try with a hello world init action?

Comment: @Christoper - Thank you for the edits.

Comment: @Dagang I ran a hello world script and it worked. If the script caused an error will the command not allow init_action to run on other vms? I am making some changes in hadoop config and the data node fails after init_action as it is expecting the same changes in the master node. But, the init_action never runs on the master node.

Comment: Does cluster creation fail? It seems that something has to have failed earlier in the process and it should cause cluster creation to fail. Any stack traces in /var/log/google-dataproc-agent*.log on the master?

Comment: According to your DataNode error log, seems you are expecting the init action to be run first on master, then workers. But init actions are run in parallel, you have to add logic to ensure they run in order.

Comment: @Dagang - Exactly. Is there a way I can do that? I see I can find ROLE and run specific code but not sure how to force the order of the init_actions. Thank you!!

Comment: @PanwarS87 I think you can simply add some wait in workers, or if you want something more reliable, write a flag file in GCS when master init is done, check that file in workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your DataNode error log, seems you are expecting the init action to be run first on master, then workers. But init actions are run in parallel, you have to add logic to sync between master and workers. I think you can simply add some wait in workers, or if you want something more reliable, write a flag file in GCS when master init is done, check that file in workers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am able to resolve the problem. Apologies for the late reply.